# Pygtk color for drag_highlight

Tags: python, drag-and-drop, gtk, pygtk

I'm trying to change the highlight color for a `gtk.EventBox`. It has a certain background color, and I want to draw a line around it with its complementary color.  I have found `drag_highlight`, which draws a line around the widget, but I have not figured out how to change the color: it's always black.  Any ideas?

Comment: You probably gonna need to write your own code for this. In the doc for `drag_highlight` mentions it connects to the `expose_event` and `draw` handlers so if you do the same and then update the style (or border) when these events happen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make the line around the `EventBox`, it is possible to put it into the `Frame` or another `EventBox` (in this case it is possible to set the width of the "border"), here is how it looks:

[image]

And here is the code (it is a [modified EventBox example](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2tutorial/ch-ContainerWidgets.html#sec-EventBox)):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# example eventbox.py

import pygtk
pygtk.require('2.0')
import gtk

class EventBoxExample:
    def __init__(self):
        window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
        window.set_title("Event Box")
        window.connect("destroy", lambda w: gtk.main_quit())
        window.set_border_width(10)

        # Create an EventBox and add it to our toplevel window
        frame = gtk.EventBox() # gtk.Frame()
        window.add(frame)
        frame.show()
        frame.set_border_width(2)
        frame.modify_bg(gtk.STATE_NORMAL,
                            frame.get_colormap().alloc_color("blue"))

        event_box = gtk.EventBox()
        frame.add(event_box)
        event_box.set_border_width(10)
        event_box.show()

        # Create a long label
        label = gtk.Label("Click here to quit, quit, quit, quit, quit")
        event_box.add(label)
        label.show()

        # Clip it short.
        label.set_size_request(110, 20)

        # And bind an action to it
        event_box.set_events(gtk.gdk.BUTTON_PRESS_MASK)
        event_box.connect("button_press_event", lambda w,e: gtk.main_quit())

        # More things you need an X window for ...
        event_box.realize()
        event_box.window.set_cursor(gtk.gdk.Cursor(gtk.gdk.HAND1))

        # Set background color to green
        event_box.modify_bg(gtk.STATE_NORMAL,
                            event_box.get_colormap().alloc_color("green"))

        window.show()

def main():
    gtk.main()
    return 0

if __name__ == "__main__":
    EventBoxExample()
    main()
```